# How to exclude posts without featured images from custom post type WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

We have the following WP_Query which collects all custom posts (except id=191) and lists them randomly:

```
$args_projekte = array(
        'post_type' => 'projekt',
        'posts_per_page' => 18,
        'post__not_in' => array(191),   
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        );
$query_projekte = new WP_Query($args_projekte);
```

How do we extend this to ALSO exclude all posts WITHOUT featured images?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a `meta_query` where you search for `_thumbnail_id`:

```
$args_projekte = array(
    'post_type' => 'projekt',
    'posts_per_page' => 18,
    'post__not_in' => array(191),   
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'meta_query' => array(array('key' => '_thumbnail_id'))
);
$query_projekte = new WP_Query($args_projekte);
```

The above verifies that the `_thumbnail_id` key exists.